# Type depends on condition in template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Can I make a template function with arguments, which types are depends on template argument? (Code below is just to explain, what I want)

```
#include <complex>

template <bool two>
void foo( (if (two) ? double* : std::complex<double>* >) input, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++n)
        input[i] *= two ? 2.0 : 1.0;
}

void foo_double(double *input, size_t n){
    foo<true>(input,n);

}

void foo_complex (std::complex<double> *input, size_t n){
    foo<false>(input,n);
}
```

I thought `std::conditional` would help, but I guess, I don't know how to use it correctly here (code below can't be compiled)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <complex>

template <bool two>
void foo(std::conditional<two, double*, std::complex<double>* > input, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++n)
        input[i] *= two ? 2.0 : 1.0;
}

void foo_double(double *input, size_t n){
    foo<true>(input,n);

}

void foo_complex (std::complex<double> *input, size_t n){
    foo<false>(input,n);
}
```

It would be very nice, if someone find solution without higher than c++11, so I will be able to compile it both in vs2012 and with gcc-6+. But some examples with c++14 or higher will be good experience too.

Thanks =)

Comment: Why do you need to even do this?  Why not `template<typename T> void foo(T input, size_t n) { ...} `?

Comment: `std::conditional` is the right choice. Did you look in the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to see how to use it? If you don't have access to C++11, you should be able to implement it yourself (it's documented if you need help).

Comment: use `std::conditional` like this: `std::conditional<some_bool, type_true, type_false>::type`

Comment: @NathanOliver, `two` is used in function body.  Type of input depends on bool, so I want to reduce template arguments

Comment: `std::conditional_t</*..*/>` in C++14, `typename std::conditional</*..*/>::type` for C++11.

Comment: @Rakete1111, i looked, but there is no good example, how to use it without typedef

Comment: @Sklert Well, implement it without a typedef. But why do you want to use it without typedef?

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you!

Comment: @Rakete1111, I don't know how to put it in function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to add a `::type` and a `typename`

```
template <bool two>
// ......*typename*.....................................................*::type*
void foo (typename std::conditional<two, double*, std::complex<double>* >::type input, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++n)
        input[i] *= two ? 2.0 : 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I will mark this answer after time limit =)

Comment: @Sklert in C++14, you can instead just change your code to `std::conditional_t` and not add the `typename` and `::type`.